# What does this Plugin Error (Flutter) mean?

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins

I have updated Flutter and now can't even use it.
The below is the message I get and have no idea how to fix it.

Plugin error

```
        Plugin 'Dart' (version '212.5744') is not compatible with the current version of the IDE, because it requires build 212.5284 or newer but the current build is AI-211.7628.21
        Plugin 'Flutter' (version '67.1.2') is not compatible with the current version of the IDE, because it requires build 212.5457.46 or newer but the current build is AI-211.7628.21
```

Comment: Try updating the IDE and Flutter plugin to the latest version.

Comment: Thank you. I had to update Flutter using flutter doctor.